# Resource Class - Azure SQL DW

Tags: azure-synapse

Just one basic query:

In Azure, SQL Datawarehouse is there a way to know about default resource class and its associated Memory, concurrency slots that are allocated for a given SQL Login User account.

Can this be retrieved from tsql code?

Answer (score 2):

In Azure Data [Warehouse resource classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/resource-classes-for-workload-management#view-the-resource-classes) are implemented through database roles.

To find out the database roles of a user you can use [this query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-role-members-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT DP1.name AS DatabaseRoleName,   
   isnull (DP2.name, 'No members') AS DatabaseUserName   
 FROM sys.database_role_members AS DRM  
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP1  
   ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP2  
   ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id  
WHERE DP1.type = 'R'
ORDER BY DP1.name;
```

AFAIK there is no DMV or predefined stored procedure that would show you the numbers for the max memory size/concurrency slot.
Having said that, on Gen1 you can use [prc_workload_management_by_DWU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/resource-classes-for-workload-management#example-code-for-finding-the-best-resource-class) to find the information you're looking for. For Gen2 you could write your own mapping stored proc based on the books online.

If you want to know the real time resource consumption take a look at [sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-pdw-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7) and joint it with [sys.dm_pdw_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-pdw-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7) on `session_id` to see which user is running each query.

Answer (score 0):

The article Pio refers to ([Workload management with resource classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/resource-classes-for-workload-management)) mentions that smallrc is the default resource class.  This applies to all logins.  On Gen1, smallrc always gets 1 concurrency slot.  On Gen2, smallrc is a dynamic resource class that adds concurrency slots as the instance is scaled.  See [Memory and concurrency limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/memory-and-concurrency-limits) for further details on how concurrency slots are allocated to smallrc and the rest of the resource classes.